# Remove entire line in text file that contain with specific word/string in python

Tags: python, string, split, extract

all. 
Im using example from SO and tried to remove few lines/string in the text file but not successful. The string line that need to be deleted for example

```
             OSPF Process 1 with Router ID 1.1.1.1
                       Area: 0.0.0.11
               Link State Database
```

I able to delete those line by specifying exactly the whole string/line as below but this can only remove one line at a time and another problem is  Router ID and Area could be any number and change dynamically.

```
filename = 'raw.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
with open('clean.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in lines:
        if 'Area: 0.0.0.10' not in line:
            fout.write(line)
```

I tried using startwith but it doesn't remove it.

```
if not line.startswith('OSPF'):
```

This is how the looks and string placement in the text file. OSPF..., Area..., Link... lines does not start from left, it start with white space, so i think this is why startswith does not work.

```
     OSPF Process 1 with Router ID 1.1.1.1
                 Area: 0.0.0.11
         Link State Database 


some textxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

         OSPF Process 1 with Router ID 2.1.1.1
                 Area: 0.0.0.12
         Link State Database 

some textxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


     OSPF Process 1 with Router ID 2.2.2.2
                 Area: 0.0.0.33
         Link State Database 

some textxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Expected like below after remove those lines

```
some textxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


some textxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


some textxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Please advise further and thank you

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

```
     OSPF Process 1 with Router ID 1.1.1.1
                 Area: 0.0.0.11
         Link State Database
```

for example above 5 lines when executed the script..it will remove 3 lines but still remain 2 lines

another example

```
 * Link ID: 10.1.155.20
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Low
                         Area: 0.0.0.13
                 Link State Database


  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.4.0.2
  Adv rtr   : 1.4.0.2
```

this have 4 lines (between Area and before Type)...when executing the script only 2 line remove...and 2 will remain....
For this... the final should be like below

```
* Link ID: 10.1.155.20
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Low

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.4.0.2
  Adv rtr   : 1.4.0.2
```

**Remove specific string and line and also its next line (after Link State Database line)**

clean.txt

```
**To remove this empty line
To remove this empty line
To remove this empty line**
  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.4.0.1
  Adv rtr   : 1.4.0.1
  Ls age    : 996
  Len       : 48
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 8000002f
  chksum    : 0xe7f5
  Link count: 2
   * Link ID: 1.16.9.9
     Data   : 10.1.155.2
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 100
   * Link ID: 10.1.155.20
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 100
     Priority : Low

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.16.9.9
  Adv rtr   : 1.16.9.9
  Ls age    : 392
  Len       : 48
  Options   :  ABR  E
  seq#      : 8000001e
  chksum    : 0x3116
  Link count: 2
   * Link ID: 1.4.0.1
     Data   : 10.242.177.21
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 1
   * Link ID: 10.1.155.20
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Low
**To remove this empty line**

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 1.4.0.2
  Adv rtr   : 1.4.0.2
  Ls age    : 1194
  Len       : 96
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 8001cf7b
  chksum    : 0xbfae
  Link count: 6
   * Link ID: 1.4.0.2
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 0
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 1.4.0.1
     Data   : 10.0.0.2
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.0.0.0
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Low
   * Link ID: 10.40.8.0
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 100
     Priority : Low
   * Link ID: 19.23.23.15
     Data   : 10.40.10.130
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 1.4.10.200
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Low
To remove this empty line

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 100.100.0.10
  Adv rtr   : 100.100.0.10
  Ls age    : 171
  Len       : 84
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 8001a292
  chksum    : 0x5fa2
  Link count: 5
   * Link ID: 100.100.0.10
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 12
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.1
     Data   : 10.10.10.18
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.10.10.17
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 19.23.23.15
     Data   : 10.10.30.30
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.90.25.30
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 10.10.0.1
  Adv rtr   : 10.10.0.1
  Ls age    : 191
  Len       : 96
  Options   :  ASBR  E
  seq#      : 80013bcf
  chksum    : 0x9871
  Link count: 6
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.1
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 12
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 15.51.51.14
     Data   : 10.10.0.130
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.129
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 100.100.0.10
     Data   : 10.10.10.17
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 10
   * Link ID: 10.10.10.18
     Data   : 255.255.255.255
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Medium
   * Link ID: 16.16.16.0
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 10
     Priority : Low

  Type      : Router
  Ls id     : 15.51.51.14
  Adv rtr   : 15.51.51.14
  Ls age    : 2487
  Len       : 60
  Options   :  ASBR  ABR  E
  seq#      : 8000003c
  chksum    : 0x1714
  Link count: 3
   * Link ID: 10.242.95.12
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Low
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.1
     Data   : 10.10.0.129
     Link Type: P-2-P
     Metric : 1
   * Link ID: 10.10.0.128
     Data   : 255.255.255.252
     Link Type: StubNet
     Metric : 1
     Priority : Low
**To remove this empty line
To remove this empty line**
```

Comment: so the lines you want to keep all have a non-white space character as first character in the line?

Comment: @AndrewAllen not really sir..some line that i need to keep also have white space but not so much like the lines that i want to remove

Answer (score 1):

Note that the line does *not* start with `OSPF`, but with a bunch of spaces, and *then* OSPF. Try to `strip` the line first. Also, `startswith` can take a tuple of possible prefixes, so you can check all in one go.

```
for line in lines:
    if not line.strip().startswith(("OSPF", "Area", "Link State")):
        fout.write(line)
```

Note that this might fail if some of the lines in the actual text also starts with `Area` or similar.

You could also use a regular expression to ensure that the line *has* to start with some spaces, and *then* one of those key words:

```
import re
for line in lines:
    if not re.match(r"\s+(Area|OSPF|Link State)", line):
        fout.write(line)
```

Comment: I need to be careful...so that it only remove specific line...another thing is which one is efficient to use sir... startswith or re .... thanks

Comment: @chenoi I don't think efficiency is a problem here. You could extend the regular expression to e.g. also include the value for "Area" in an abstract way, then it will certainly only match those lines.

Comment: Hi sir..I have tested and it works...but when I use clean.txt with another script it run ok but somehow Im also getting null value...for this solution it works. Thank you sir

Comment: this happen due to empty lines...need to remove (1) top empty lines (2) bottom empty lines and (3) remove any 2 empty lines to only 1

Comment: Hi sir.... when remove those lines it will also create new single line. Is it possible to not create that new line when executing the script above? Thanks

Comment: i does not create new line...but that empty line is the existing line... meaning that script above will only remove those specific line/string..but not include empty line below it... pls refer to update statement above. thanks

Comment: Hi sir, how can i extend it to also remove/delete line after it..what i mean is to remove line below line Link State Database... thus...remove line of OSPF...line of Area... line of Link State...and one line below it... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to find some specific text and remove it. Below is the sample code, you can play with different regex as per your requirements.

try below code:

```
import re
regex = "OSPF|Area|Link"
for line in lines:
    if not re.findall(regex, line):
        print line
```

Answer (score 1):

What you might do instead of reading line by line is to read the entire content of the text file and use a pattern for that specific match taking the parts of the digits into account that can vary.

```
^[ \t]*OSPF Process \d+ with Router ID \d+(?:\.\d+){3}\s*Area: \d+(?:\.\d+){3}\s*Link State Database\s*(?:\n|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[ \t]*` Match 0+ times a space or tab
- `OSPF Process \d+ with Router ID \d+(?:\.\d+){3}` Match text taking the format of the digits `\d+` for Process and  Router ID into account
- `\s*Area: \d+(?:\.\d+){3}` Match `Area:` followed by 1+ digits and repeat 3 times a dot and 1+ digits
- `\s*Link State Database` Match 0+ times a whitespace char and literal text
- `\s*(?:\n|$)` Match 0+ times a whitespace char and then match either a newline or assert the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sZJHxQ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ka9Bqw)

For example:

```
import re

filename = 'raw.txt'
pattern = r"^[ \t]*OSPF Process \d+ with Router ID \d+(?:\.\d+){3}\s*Area: \d+(?:\.\d+){3}\s*Link State Database\s*(?:\n|$)"
with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
    res = re.sub(pattern, "", fin.read(), 0, re.MULTILINE)
    text_file = open("clean.txt", "w")
    text_file.write(res)
    text_file.close()
```

**Edit**

To match a empty newline after, you could use add after Database:

- `[ \t]*` Match 0+ times a space or string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:\r?\n|\r)[ \t]*` Match a newline followed by matching 0+ times a tab or space
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `$` Assert end of the string

Full pattern:

```
^[ \t]*OSPF Process \d+ with Router ID \d+(?:\.\d+){3}\s*Area: \d+(?:\.\d+){3}\s*Link State Database[ \t]*(?:(?:\r?\n|\r)[ \t]*)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bzvKVE/1/)

Comment: Hi sir...this work ...but I'm getting error when I pass the clean.txt to be read by another script (to extract specific string and line).. but for the purpose of removing whitespace and specifc string...it does work. Thanks

Comment: Hi sir, it does remove as require ..how can i extend it to also remove/delete line after it..what i mean is to remove line below line Link State Database... thus...remove line of OSPF...line of Area... line of Link State...and one line below it... thanks

Comment: @chenoi If you want to remove a single line after you could match an optional empty line and assert the end of the string `^[ \t]*OSPF Process \d+ with Router ID \d+(?:\.\d+){3}\s*Area: \d+(?:\.\d+){3}\s*Link State Database[ \t]*(?:(?:\r?\n|\r)[ \t]*)?$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bzvKVE/1)